# Reading json from a site for an app

Tags: ios, json, http

I am learning to build a movie app and would like to retrieve details about movies from a website like www.gv.com.sg.

Currently, I am gaining clarity over how json works and how to fetch data from the site. Can someone please enlighten more about how I can retrieve the list of movies and showtimes from the website?

I have read tutorials on json and posts on this site, but am unsure of how to proceed. A nudge in the right direction is all I seek.

Comment: First you need to see if they will provide a way for you to retrieve json.

Comment: How can I do that? Using developer tools on chrome

Comment: That's not going to help you fetch JSON.

Comment: I understand, how can I view it?